# How to solve Route not found error in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I am passing a route and trying to show on view page, but it's giving me route not found error, please check my code and let me know where i am mistaking.

here is my route.php file..

```
    Route::get('amenities-view', 'PropertyController@amenitiesview');
```

Here are my controller.php file..

```
public function amenitiesview()
{
    $amenities=Amenity::all();
    return view('admin.amenities.amenity', compact($amenities));
}
```

here are my leftsidebar.blade.php file (Where i am clicking and going to amenity.blade.php file)

```
<li>
<a href="{{route('amenities.amenity')}}">
    Amenities List
    </a>
</li>
```

and here is my amenity.blade.php file..

```
@extends('layouts.adminPanel') 
@section('body')
<body class="page-ecommerce-product">
@endsection
@section('admin-content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none;">
            <ul id="blogErrors">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-action">
                    <button class="btn btn-close"></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-min"></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-expand"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-title">Add Amenities</div>
                <p>Code Here</p>
            </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->


        </div><!--/.panel-->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: please try to add `->name('amenities.amenity')` at the end of your route declaration

Comment: hi, check route list with artisan command ( php artisan route:list ) but add name for your route

Comment: Thank You @dparoli, It's working....Can u please tell me why we use this.

Comment: @SumitSaini `route()` is a helper function that will return the full URL of the route in Blade.  But you can only use it with named routes.

Comment: I am getting error undefined variable amenities on view file...here is my code
`<label class="block">
@foreach($amenities as $ami)
 <div class="icheckbox_line-grey">
     <input type="checkbox" class="icheck-line-grey" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<div class="icheck_line-icon"></div>{{$ami->am_name}}<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;">
</ins>
</div>
@endforeach
</label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a route without naming it. use like below

```
Route::get('amenities-view', 'PropertyController@amenitiesview')->name('amenities.amenity');
```

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes) about named routing.

Comment: in which view??